# My "iframe" Button to Trigger an IFTTT Webhook Works on Chrome but not Firefox, Is There a More Correct/Future-Proof Method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cross-browser, content-security-policy

I have a working IIS server/playground and have been messing in HTML with ways to activate my lights remotely as a proof of concept. My line of thinking is that if I can make *this* work, I can reasonably make a lot of other more complex things also work.

**Good news**- I'm able to use a button on my page to trigger IFTTT on chrome and make the lights randomize color as intended, **bad news** it doesn't work on Firefox and I'm not even sure it's a good (re: future-proof) way to make it happen in the first place.

I have a suspicion this is related to Content-Security-Policy and inline iframe activation, but I don't know enough about these things to know 1) If I'm going in the right direction and 2) Where it's falling apart exactly. I've refactored my code to be a little more modular per some guidelines found here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

and I've also added a custom HTTP Response Header through IIS that essentially looks like `Content-Security-Policy: script-src http://example.net 'self'`

There are 3 files interacting with each other: "index.html" for the page/button which invokes "button.js", "button.js" for the iframe function which invokes "test.php", and "test.php" for the private key/link that has to be opened/refreshed through the nominally invisible iframe.

The index.html contains this:

```
<script src='button.js'></script>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" id="button">
Randomize the Light Color in Simon's Room
    <div id="iframeHolder"/>
</button>
```

(The mdl part refers to Google's Material Design Lite which is imported elsewhere in the script, though it could just as easily be a regular button)

In practice this correctly produces a button that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXEPt.png

The button.js contains this:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(){ 
            if(!$('#iframe').length) {
                $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="http://REDACTED.net/test.php" width="0" height="0" border="0" border-width="0"></iframe>');
                } 
                  iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
                });   
                });
```

Where "REDACTED" is the domain of my site

Test.php contains this:

```
<?php
$ifttturl = 
  file('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/web_switch/with/key/REDACTED');
?>
```

Where "REDACTED" is my 43-character key tied to my IFTTT account.

Note: Visiting "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/web_switch/with/key/REDACTED" or refreshing the page while on that link is enough to trigger the webhook properly, but the appeal in doing it with a button is not having to leave the original web page for a blank screen.

On Chrome, this exact setup already works *perfectly*. On Firefox this fails without any fanfare or errors- the button is pressed and nothing happens.

Comment: Why not just do things with ajax?

Comment: Because https://i.imgur.com/eYiDeYS.png 
I sincerely don't know much about what I've cobbled together, let alone the first thing about Ajax

Comment: Have you taken a look in Firefox's developer tools (F12 typically) and the network tab in particular when clicking the button?  I would expect (but don't have a setup to test with) that you might find a clue as to what's failing in there.

Comment: The network tools seem to indicate that just about every file is loading locally, minus "test.php" (which is roughly intended behavior meant to preserve the private key contained inside). This is why I suspected CSP in the first place, but I don't know enough about using the Dev tools for troubleshooting/debugging to fix it.

Comment: If it were CSP-related, the browser would be logging a message about CSP explicitly in the devtools console. So if you’re not seeing such a message in the devtools console, then you can rule out CSP as the cause.